Can I use a loader out of a route?
I'm using React Router's loader to "send" the loaded data to a component via its route in the App.jsx component, like this
<Route 
  path="vans" 
  element={<HostVans />}
  errorElement={<Error />} 
  loader={hostVansLoader} 
/>

This way, I can load the vans data before the HostVans.jsx component loads, instead of using useEffect to fetch the vans data while the component loads.
Then, in the HostVans.jsx component, I'm receiving the data using useLoaderData, like this:
import { useSearchParams, useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom"

...

const vans = useLoaderData();

However, in different place in my app, I'm also using the HostVans.jsx component as a nested / child component to another parent component, and that means the HostVans.jsx component isn't loaded via route but just called inside the Dashboard.jsx component, like this:
<div className="container dashboard-container">
  ... 
  <section className="row reviews-section">
    <div className="col-10">
      <h2 className="reviews-heading">Review score</h2>
      <FaStar className="reviews-icon"/>
      <p className="review-score">5.0<span>/5</span></p>
    </div>
    <div className="col-2">
      <Link to="#">Details</Link>
    </div>
  </section>
 </div>
 <HostVans />

Is there any way I can "send" the vans data via the loader when there's no routing involved (when the component is called inside another component)?
I tried this, but it's not working:
<HostVans loader={hostVansLoader} />

In other words, the HostVans.jsx component is coded so that it's expecting the loader data, but when called from Dashboard.jsx (no routing involved), the data is not being sent. How can I solve it?
EDIT: as requested, here's the routing setup in the App.jsx component:
const router = createBrowserRouter(createRoutesFromElements(
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />} >
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
    <Route 
      path="vans" 
      element={<Vans />}
      errorElement={<Error />} 
      loader={vansLoader} 
    />
    <Route path="vans/:id" element={<VanDetails />} />
    {/* Host */}
    <Route path="host" element={<HostLayout />} >
      <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route path="income" element={<Income />} />
      <Route 
        path="vans" 
        element={<HostVans />}
        errorElement={<Error />}
      /> 
      <Route path="reviews" element={<Reviews />} />
      <Route path="vans/:id" element={<HostVanDetailsLayout />} >
        <Route index element={<HostVanDetailsDefault />} />
        <Route path="pricing" element={<HostVanDetailsPricing />} />
        <Route path="photos" element={<HostVanDetailsPhotos />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />}/>
  </Route>
))

function App() {

  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  )

}

function vansLoader(){
    return getVans();
}

function hostVansLoader(){
    return getHostVans();
}

export { App as default, vansLoader, hostVansLoader }

Here, the Dashboard.jsx component, where HostVans.jsx gets also called as a child component:
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa6";

import HostVans from "./HostVans"

const Dashboard = () => {

    return (
      <>
        <div className="container dashboard-container">
          <section className="row income-section">
            <div className="col-10">
              <h1 className="income-heading">
                Welcome!
              </h1>
              <p>Income last <span>30 days</span></p>
              <p className="income-figure">$2,260</p>
            </div>
            <div className="col-2">
              <Link to="#">Details</Link>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section className="row reviews-section">
            <div className="col-10">
              <h2 className="reviews-heading">Review score</h2>
              <FaStar className="reviews-icon"/>
              <p className="review-score">5.0<span>/5</span></p>
            </div>
            <div className="col-2">
              <Link to="#">Details</Link>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        {/* HostVans called here as child component  */}
        <HostVans />
      </>
  )
}

export default Dashboard


No, but you can use the useRouteLoaderData hook to load the data that was loaded by the "vans" route loader. You could also use the same hostVansLoader loader on the other route that eventually renders HostVans. If you need more help than this can you [edit] to share a more complete [mcve] of the router and routes, and where the more deeply nested HostVans "instance" is rendered?

Thanks for your quick answer. useRouteLoaderData looks like an interesting tool to access data from any route. However, in the HostVans.jsx component, I need to know whether the vans data is coming from useloaderData or from useRouteLoaderData. The way I see it, I should somehow make HostVans.jsx dynamic to load data one way or the other, depending on how the component is loaded, am I right? However, I have no idea how to achieve that.
As for the minimal reproducible example, what do you need? I mean, the App is quite complex at this point. Thanks.

useLoaderData is basically a more specific version of useRouteLoaderData where the specific "route" is just the current route. You could use useRouteLoaderData and specify the one "vans" route id. For the minimal example, I was asking to see the router and routes setup, the Dashboard component, and everything between to be able to see the complete path where your data is flowing/processing.

I just edited my question to add more code :)

Apparently I've previously answered a very similar question before. Does Can useLoaderData be used in the sibling components of the component in which loader() is used help answer your question? Here's a small demo sandbox.

Oh, now I see it! So the trick was to promote the loader to the parent route, in this case /host, so the data that is accesible at HostVans regardless of how the component is loaded. I tried and it worked. Thanks a lot, man!
